# Code coverage is always shown as zero percent using Eclemma plugin

Tags: junit, eclemma

I am using EclEmma plugin for getting the code coverage for a package.
But it always shows 0% as the coverage.

Is there anything which I am missing out as part of configuration
Please help.

Comment: You did not tell us what you have done? How should anybody know what you might miss?

Comment: I have installed it through these steps: Eclipse-> help-> install new software- > Add-> Archive-> selected the eclemma zip file having the installation software. Apart from this i have not done any configuration

Comment: Do you use PowerMock by any chance? If so, it won't work with EclEmma. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363212/powermock-eclemma-coverage-issue) post

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363212/powermock-eclemma-coverage-issue