# How to start debug a program: know which code has just run when perform an action on GUI?

Tags: java, debugging, eclipse-rcp

I usually have to debug some programs. Those are not my code. Example in a Java Eclipse RCP app. I have to do some actions on the GUI, then find out which code has implemented those actions to research the code. In almost cases, I just guess then set some breakpoints to follow the flow of the program in the call stack. Guess then try. Some times is quick. Many times is slowly. I just want to know if there are a technical to know which code has just run if I perform an action on the GUI. Can you share it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe try a code coverage tool.

Comment: I believe this is already answered on: [eclipse-plugin-for-code-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046212/3733369) it's very complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some code coverage tool.

Here are some code coverage tools listed: [Java Code Coverage Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools).

If you are using Eclipse IDE [Jacoco](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) is easy to use.